# Spinner not displaying the selected item Android

Tags: java, android

I´m loading a list from a JSON from a DB. I set an adapter using this list and add it to my Spinner. When I click on the spinner I can see the list of elements that were added. When I click on one of this elements I do get the Toast with the value but is not displayed once the spinner is closed.

I´m using setSelection on my Spinner but doesn't seem to do the job.

Thank you for your help as always.

ArrayAdapter adapter;

```
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, brands);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        marca.setAdapter(adapter);

        marca.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                marca.setSelection(0, false);
            }
        });

        marca.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                marca.setSelection(position);
                marcaMandar = brands.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), marcaMandar, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
```

Comment: What is displayed?

Comment: This is how it looks
https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNHXQtUOo4KmRIuCEs20DEj8w1a8S5_0MD-D4u7T7njwcnBNceU1xb-GOthlRnnPA?key=VDJSYmgzbHJCMXFyb3lrUHJsNGdQaVM0aVQ2TlBn

https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMtM2Ef_Xzj82D1n_ZmyFZIvMqrDfqOOk9egVkdYlBGiYtVGscorcE6gRgcRFshpQ?key=QVF6NHV2QmI0elJNM3ZVRWkyOE55Q1ZHREpPTzBn

https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPDmDZOLsd9N8Kq3vljGX6s58C8noadKnH3isvZ6KcpYzPdq6zck2L6elPv8wMi8Q?key=WE5CTVk2eDBEVTN5MFRzLWVxRE54Qlljamc2M2Rn

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In those screen-shots marca Abarth is displayed in spinner after is selected. I don't understand your problem.. You don't need to setSelection manually. Is made automatically.

Comment: But I need to be able to see the selection on the spinner itself, not on a Toast.

Comment: Do you mean to change color of text? As far i can see, is White and this can be a problem..

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will refresh the UI control attached to the adapter to modify it and display the selected item.

As mentioned in Android's reference:

> notifyDataSetChanged()
>
> Notifies the attached observers that the
>   underlying data has been changed and **any View** reflecting the data set
>   should **refresh itself**.

Comment: This are the changes I made, still not working but thank you for the answer.
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, modelos);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            modelo.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work after a lot of trial and error. It appears that the default layout type needs to be changed and that made it work. Thanks a lot to everyone who answered.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Preferencias.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, brands);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    marca.setAdapter(adapter);
```